# Como acessar os SQLs dos updates feitos pelo orm:schema do Doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-2, orm

Estou com uma aplicação rodando em um servidor (produção) que não dá permissão de acesso ao `../vendor/bin/doctrine` e por isso não consigo rodar os comandos, como o `orm:schema-tool:update`, por exemplo. Estou executando os comandos no meu ambiente de desenvolvimento, normalmente.

Como faço para acessar os comandos executados pelo `orm:schema` para que eu possa rodá-los corretamente em meu ambiente de produção, simulando a ação do próprio ORM e mantendo os bancos devidamente pareados?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao invés de acessar o comandos do executável `../vendor/bin/doctrine`, você pode criar um script, acessível via web (claro, com alguma autenticação necessária) para fazer o que precisa.

Veja [essa seção na documentação do Doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html#database-schema-generation).

Resumidamente, basta instanciar o `SchemaTool` passando seu `EntityManager` como argumento, e chamar o método `updateSchema` passando as classes de sua aplicação como argumento:

```
<?php

$tool = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool($em);

$classes = array(
  $em->getClassMetadata('Entities\User'),
  $em->getClassMetadata('Entities\Profile')
);

$tool->updateSchema($classes);
```

Comment: Grato @Rodrigo Rigotti